# getting following error on ubuntu 22.04 when trying to ssh into any server. debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, cipher

Very annoying but solved by uncommenting:

vim  /etc/ssh/ssh_config

```
Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
```